# Problem with table view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Here is my code for creating a cell

---

cell.textLabel.text=[listdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];
    if(indexPath.row==1)
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"Some text";
    return cell;

---

Here are total 20 rows and only 8 rows are visible at a time

My problem is that detail text label it repeated at many rows when i do scrolling....

please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [listdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (indexPath.row == 1)
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Some text";
else
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
return cell;
```

Table cells are recycled, so you have to reset everything every time.